# Get file name from remote server path with python

Tags: python, path

```
path = '\\data\\d\g\t\5\filename.txt'
path.split('\')
['', 'data', 'd', 'g\t\x05\x0cilename.txt']
```

How can I get only `filename` from this path?

Comment: is that path correct? after d it should be d\\g\\t\\5\\filename

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like this. Get only the file name then strip the extension.

```
full_file_name = os.path.basename(file_path)

file_name, extension = os.path.splitext(full_file_name)
```

You can also split the path to get the file name

```
file_dir, file_name = os.path.split(file_path)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if the path you provided is correct. If you have missed backslashes then you can use pathlib:

> path = "\data\d\g\t\5\filename.txt"

```
from pathlib import Path

p = Path("\\data\\d\\g\\t\\5\\filename.txt")

print(p.name.split('.')[0])

# Output
# filename
```

If it isn't a typo, you can use raw strings

> path = "\data\d\g\t\5\filename.txt"

```
path = r"\\data\\d\g\t\5\filename.txt"

print(path.split('\\')[-1].split('.')[0])

# Output
# filename
```

In either case you can use raw string and use : `p.split('\\')[-1].split('.')[0]`